# Change text on tkinter button during call back execution

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, tkinter, sleep

I'm trying to change the text on a button when the call back of that particular button executing.

Let's say I have "Run" as the text on my button, and I want to change it to "Running" just after it has been clicked, and during the call back execution.

After the completion of call back execution, I want to change it back to "Run".

I am not getting which part of my code is buggy.

```
import Tkinter as tk
import time

root = tk.Tk()

def change():
    button.config(text='Running')
    button.config(state='disabled')
    print "start"
    time.sleep(5)
    print "end"
    button.config(state='normal')
    button.config(text="Run")

button = tk.Button(root,text="Run",command=change)
button.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sleep makes the WHOLE program stop for a moment, including the interface, usually stopping it from changing the interface itself, due to how the mainloop works.

Here, try the `.after` function, this should work fine.

```
import Tkinter as tk
import time

root = tk.Tk()

def change():
    button.config(text='Running')
    button.config(state='disabled')
    print "start"
    root.after(5000,changeback)
def changeback():
    print "end"
    button.config(state='normal')
    button.config(text="Run")

button = tk.Button(root,text="Run",command=change)
button.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

`root.after(5000,changeback)` will call a command after `5000` milliseconds, or 5 seconds without stopping the whole program, that being `changeback()`